# table with 25 columns of varchar(1000) problems

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a table with 24 columns of varchar(1000) and 1 column with varchar(8000), my source is of same data lengths of text files. Would I get any problems in the processing due to data lenghs in performance or over size of the sql limit page size.

Comment: i think a block size greater than your row size would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. If at all possible change those columns to varChar(max). You may lose a bit of performance, but that sure beats losing data due to truncation.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample test by taking 1000 length for 24 columns and 8000 length for 1 column I got less than 8060 bytes of row size on the table, which is ok for SQL server.

thanks

prav

Comment: Put this in your original question.

Comment: Just because you are not hitting the limit now, doesn't mean you won't in the future.  This structure is a time bomb.